# Django 1.6 how to first filter according to another model, then order the model?

Tags: django

Ok, the order fields in Question is dynamic. Not only 'votes', depend on which field user choose.

If there are two models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField()  
    title = models.CharField()  
    content = models.TextField()
    votes = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edit_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Label(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)  
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

An question may have many labels. if I want to get all questions whose label_set has a label named 'python', then order these questions by 'votes' or by 'create_time' or any other field. How to? This is what I tried:

```
res=[]
for question in Question.objects.all():
    if 'python' in question.label_set.all():
        res.append(question)
```

But then how to order res by 'vote'? I've read the tutorial but no results. Plus, I feel this way not the best way. Which way is the best?

Is there a way like:

```
Question.objects.filter(label_set__contains='python').oder_by('votes')
```

I really hope...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list of filtering criteria with ordering information as a list

```
order_crit = {
    'python': ['votes'],
    'django': ['create_time', 'votes']
}

You can use `*` to unpack values in a list like

Question.objects.filter(label__name__contains=filter_crit).oder_by(*order_crit[filter_crit])
```

So if you wish to filter them by *python*

```
filter_crit = 'python'
Question.objects.filter(label__name__contains=filter_crit).order_by(*order_crit[filter_crit])
```

Following will result in following:

```
Question.objects.filter(label__name__contains='python').order_by('votes')
```

Because `*` will unpack your list as `argument values` within `order_by`. You can use multiple fields for ordering by adding the fields to the lists in `order_crit`

Comment: `filter(label_set__contains='python')` is made by me, not existing in Django.so...

Comment: Ahhh, I missed it, I update my answer. You can use reverse relations for that. You must use model name in lowercase letters for using reverse relations.

Comment: Thank you very much. Plus, it surprises me that there does exists  a `contains` like thing in django! It is really amazing!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make a meta class inside the mode ([doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering)) :

e.g.:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField()  
    title = models.CharField()  
    content = models.TextField()
    votes = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['votes']
```

Also for making queries, you do not need to make array and append yourself. Django provides a lot of ways to make queries. [Read here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: the order field is dynamic. So Meta is not the solution.

Comment: Plus could you show me the code not using array to get the `res` in the example? I don't see the solution in the doc

Comment: So, you want to get all the question that have label name = python, right?  Then, all_labels = Label.objects.get(name = "python)  now you use _set, as in: all_labels.question_set.all()

Comment: So, it finds all the labels first with name  = python, and then reverse searches all the relevant questions.

Comment: Label.objects.get(name = 'python') is totaly not working, the `name` is not unique